# Icon to designate use/usage

Tags: icon, symbolism

I'm looking for suggestions for an icon to represent 'use' e.g. leather can be used for shoes, clothing etc or shell can be used for scraping, cutting, adornment etc.

So in this context usage is quite wide.

So far I have a 'spanner'.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GD.SE! Couple of questions: What is your web/app about? Is the icon going to be along others, and if so, which ones? I'm having a little trouble understanding exactly what the icon would represent, any chance you can share a screen of your interface or similar?

Comment: At the risk of questioning your question: are you sure the question isn't (using your examples) "I'm looking for icons for leather & shell" or "I'm looking for icons for shoes, clothing, scraping, cutting, adornment".

Usually you'd want an icon for a specific verb or noun.
Also, I think you're wrong about spanner - it's already got a bunch of meanings more specific than your intended one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a checkbox with a v
[image]
Or some sort of search recults, like something inside the magnifying glass
[image]